# Is it possible to write dynamic SQL queries in arcgis layers based on the URL?

Tags: arcgis

I have an arcgis layer available at for example, https://baseURL/myMapServer/0
I want to define a query for this layer based on the input parameters.
For example:

```
select * from my_table where category = ::category
```

And pass the category as a URL parameter, for example:

```
https://baseURL/myMapServer/0?category=cat1
```

How can I do that?

Note:

I've tried:

```
https://baseURL/myMapServer/0/query=category=cat1
```

And define my query as:

```
select * from my_table where category = ::category
```

But arcgis says that the query syntax is incorrect complaining about ::category.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could publish a mapserver with a query layer with the following definition:

```
select * from my_table
```

Then you would filter the categories using REST service through the following URL:

```
https://baseURL/myMapServer/0/query?category='cat1'
```

Notice that cat1 may be case sensitive. Then, you should check if your value in the database is cat1 or CAT1 or Cat1. Using geodatabase in Oracle this happens.

Also notice, that the quotes ('cat1') are important. You should urlencode them. Also, use question mark to pass parameters to the 'query' method.